# Convert HierarchyId to string - unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.String'

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ef-core-3.1

I'm using HierarchyId in my EFCore3.1, I have separated Read and Write in my application,
In read, I have created a Model as below:

```
public class Category
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    // removed for brevity
}
```

I should mention that in write it works fine.
this is my model that I use in write:

```
public class Category
{
    public HierarchyId Id{ get; }
    // removed for brevity
}
```

I need when I run my application I get following error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.String'.

Is there any way to convert HierarchyId to string?

**Edit**:
I use **entityframeworkcore.sqlserver.hierarchyid** package.

Comment: I edited the post. forgot to type Id in here.

Comment: It seems like you should also [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72024327/edit) your question to show the code that throws the exception. The answer can't be as simple as `Id.ToString()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I had to do:

```
      builder.Property( x => x.Id )
             .HasConversion(
                            v =>HierarchyId.Parse( v ),
                            v => v.ToString() ) ;
```